# The Robot Framework and the Chrome fail to click button in the special case

Tags: robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

My test (about 200 lines) is working fine with ie. The application is the React Javascript application. When I run it in the Unix with the Chrome it is failing about 1 time of 5. In failing situation screen shots are not generated so I'm not sure what is problem. 9 test cases of the 10 are successfull at least.

When I run the test case (here 3 last lines)

```
...
Wait Until Element Is Clickable    xpathOfTheDeleteButton
Click Element    xpathOfTheDeleteButton
Wait Until Page Not Contains Element    xpathOfTheDeleteButton
```

with the Chrome in the Windows I got the error message:

```
Element xpathOfTheDeleteButtondid not disappear in 5 seconds
```

for the last line. The xpathOfTheDeleteButton is referencing for the delete button which deletes the text field and the delete button itself. The test lives the web page open and then I can click manually the button and element xpathOfTheDeleteButton disappears. So it seems the application works correctly.

The xpath is

xpath=//html/body/div[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/button[@id="uniqueIdOfTheDeleteButton"]/img

This xpath is the parameter for the above 3 lines. And 2 first lines don't generate error message.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: in my experience chrome tends to be a bit faster than IE, how does this behave in firefox?

You mention screenshots are not generated, why?  Can you make sure they are?  The issue, especially as it's intermittent looks like a timing issue.    Finally you're using a horrible xpath, you state the id for the delete button is 'unique' - why do you need the huge xpath then?

Comment: I managed the fix the problem. The broblem was that the delete button didn't contained the actual image. This wasn't OK for the Chrome. Also there was hoover function over the button and maybe missing picture caused problem. The second problem was that when I later saved the page the saving was some cases not finished... But everything is working fine now. It took a lot of time to fix this problem. The long xpath is not needed.

Comment: well done for catching and fixing the problem @Sakke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the fix the problem. The broblem was that the delete button didn't contained the actual image. This wasn't OK for the Chrome. Also there was hoover function over the button and maybe missing picture caused problem. The second problem was that when I later saved the page the saving was some cases not finished... But everything is working fine now. It took a lot of time to fix this problem. The long xpath is not needed.